# Unable to reach site in PHP with GET

Tags: php, get

Whenever I visit this URL in my browser, it works fine and the file uploads to my account:

```
http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json?key=<my key>&image=<url to image>
```

But when I attempt to retrieve it in PHP with something like `file_get_contents`, I get this error message:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(<URL>): failed to open stream:
HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

You can see an example with this URL: http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json?key=&image=https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png

**Edit**: I also attempted to use a user agent but to no avail.

Comment: Curious, what happens when you run wget THATURL from the prompt? (assuming you're using linux)

Comment: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request`. What does this mean?

Comment: Try changing the user agent of the request using `cURL`

Comment: Forgot to mention in my original post that I attempted to do this but it didn't work.

Comment: Does `file_get_contents` want to retrieve data through `http` or `https`?

Comment: Can you update your question woth relevant code?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710147/php-get-content-of-http-400-response and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535799/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curl, it could be simply url_fopen is disabled in your php

it also gives you full control to change user-agent

Use this code:

```
function getContentWithCurl($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        // Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , ">>>PUT_USER_AGENT_HERE<<<" );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);

        // Get the response and close the channel.
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
```

getContentWithCurl( "YOUR_URL_HERE" );

Comment: This worked, I'm not too familiar with `curl` but I've been meaning to explore it more; this is a reason to start, I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Why does curl work even with bad request and file_get_contents doesn't?

Comment: If allow_url_fopen = Off file_get_contents is allowed to open local files only, I think this is the case here

Answer (score 1):

Bad request mostly means that one the parameters you gave are wrong. What I always do is test the API by sending a request from my webbrowser. I test the URL and check the result.

Comment: I did this, I checked that URL in my browser and it worked fine, then I attempted to use retrieve it in PHP and got that error.